# How to i create walls in a game while the game is running?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, tkinter-canvas, python-turtle

Im making a game with python turtle modual. Its supposed to be a basic 2d minecraft clone to test the idea for future projects. I dont know how to creat walls/"build them" apart from spawning in a new turtle as a cube to act like a wall. As you may understand this would be alot of turtles and i would like to know if anyone has a better way of doing it.

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

def move_left():
  screen_move1 = -1
  player_move = 40
  if t.xcor() < -360:
    screen_move1 = 0
    player_move = 0
  canvas.xview_scroll(screen_move1, "units")
  t.setx(t.xcor() - player_move)

def move_right():
  screen_move = 1
  player_move = 40
  if t.xcor() > 360:
    screen_move = 0
    player_move = 0
  canvas.xview_scroll(screen_move, "units")
  t.setx(t.xcor() + player_move)

def move_up():
  screen_move1 = -1
  player_move = 40
  if t.ycor() > 360:
    screen_move1 = 0
    player_move = 0
  canvas.yview_scroll(screen_move1, "units")
  t.sety(t.ycor() + player_move)

def move_down():
  screen_move = 1
  player_move = 40
  if t.ycor() < -360:
    screen_move = 0
    player_move = 0
  canvas.yview_scroll(screen_move, "units")
  t.sety(t.ycor() - player_move)

screen = Screen()
screen.screensize(1100,1100)
screen.setup(400,400)
screen.bgcolor("lightgreen")

canvas = screen.getcanvas()
canvas.config(xscrollincrement=str(40))
canvas.config(yscrollincrement=str(40))
canvas.xview_moveto(20)
canvas.yview_moveto(-20)

pen = Turtle()
pen.speed(0)
pen.hideturtle()
pen.pensize(4)
pen.up()
pen.setposition(400,400)
pen.down()
pen.setheading(180)

for i in range(4):
  pen.forward(800)
  pen.left(90)

t = Turtle()
t.speed(0)
t.turtlesize(2,2)
t.up()
t.setheading(90)
t.color("blue")
t.shape("square")
t.setposition(380,380)

screen.listen()
screen.onkey(move_left, "Left")
screen.onkey(move_right, "Right")
screen.onkey(move_up, "Up")
screen.onkey(move_down, "Down")
```

This is what ive done so far.

Comment: It's not really clear what a "wall" is in this context, exactly.

Comment: The turtle module is only a way to move a graphic pen.  It was not really created to be part of, say, a game engine.  If you want to do actual game programming, you probably want pygame or similar framework, not turtle graphics.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `penup` / `pendown` to safely move your turtle to the "wall" location:

```
import turtle as t

s = t.Screen()
s.setup(600, 400)


def wall(x, y):
    t.penup()
    t.goto(x, y)
    t.pendown()
    t.begin_fill()
    for i in range(4):
        t.fd(40)
        t.rt(90)
    t.end_fill()


s.onclick(wall)
s.mainloop()
```

[image]